# TFS Error: "Source Control - Unable to Access Database"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am currently using TFS with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and getting this error when I try to open up my solution:

`The associated source control plug-in is not installed or could not be initialized. Common causes for this error include server unavailability and/or incorrect workspace mappings.`

My connection to TFS and the VPN we have to use work, I have tried them on another machine and there are no problems. There is only a problem on my machine. It isn't holding any of the bindings either.

What could the problem be? Something with my install of Visual Studio?

Comment: Try removing project from source control and then ReBind it to TFS. That may work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like your bindings to the TFS server are messed up in your solution file. You should try removing the bindings manually in there by editing the solution file using a text editor.

There should be a *Global* section in the file, which is where all of the settings for this are located. look for *GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)* and remove that entire section down to *EndGlobalSection*.

Once you do that, reload the solution and tell it to go back online and your bindings should be working again.

Answer (score 3):

I opened a solution in VS2010 (not my project), and got the same message. It gave me the options to either temporarily work with the solution uncontrolled, or to permanently remove source control association bindings.
I went with the option to permanently remove source control association bindings.

Now open your project/solution.
Goto File -> Source Control -> Change source control
Select your projects and click bind.

Now bindings are correctly working online.
This is how i was able to fix this issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't see "Change source control" at File -> Source Control, in Visual Studio 2010.  Any hints?

Comment: I am no more using visual studio :-/

Answer (score 2):

I had to reset my Visual Studio configuration and cache by following the below steps:

Delete the contents from the following folders

C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon

Go to the Visual Studio IDE folder in command prompt and Run the following command "devenv /resetuserdata" from the Visual Studio IDE folder.

Typical location for 62 bit: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
Typical location for 32 bit: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

I found these steps in the article below:

[If you have problems with TFS or Visual Studio flush the user cache … or not?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, you should summarize or quote the linked article because links tend to decay over time.

Comment: Sorry @pinckerman wasn't sure about posting steps that someone else had given me. Sort of felt like I would take credit for another persons work.

Comment: Don't worry about that, if you leave the link to the original article. But you should write something else because if someone find your answer and the link is no more available it will be quite useless.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new Solution? This error is often caused when a solution has been bound to another source control system (VSS for example). It could be that the other machine you tried had VSS installed and your machine doesn't.

Try [unbinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181375.aspx) the solution, then go to tools, Options, source control and make sure TFS is selected. finally rebind the solution.

Comment: I checked that and TFS is indeed checked. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the suggestions. I tried all of those and neither of them worked. What I ended up having to do was create a new User Account on my machine, delete the original folder to where I had my mappings and Redo the Get Process for my project and everything worked fine. I guess something must have been corrupt on my User Account.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to eliminate the error by performing File | Source Control | Open from Source Control.  You will be asked whether to overwrite existing files; answer "yes".
(You should, of course, back up your source code first.)

Note, this was on VS2008; I have not tried it on VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone (like me) who was looking for an answer to this . . .

I had the same issue, and I came across a couple of things that might be helpful.

First, I found [this link on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/tfsgeneral/thread/8b699130-4418-462c-a552-ca06d7525ccf?prof=required).

Second, I opened a solution in VS2010 (not my project), and got the same message.  It gave me the options to either temporarily work with the solution uncontrolled, or to permanently remove source control association bindings.  I went with the latter (again, this was a project I inherited, not one I built), and it seems to be okay.

To anyone who finds this, I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this problem. I tried everything in this thread and nothing seemed to work. Then I found this solution by Patrick B Cahill on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36dce76e-15fc-4885-9ed6-6570edc8a31c/the-user-name-0-is-not-a-fullyqualified-user-name-error-on-build-server-since-upgrading-to-tfs?forum=tfsgeneral):

"As soon as I installed both [TFS 2010 Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20506) and [Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server Compatibility GDR](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082) respectively and rebooted, the builds started working."

This solution fixed all of my problems.

Answer (score -1):

When in doubt, I've just reintalled the TFS client (my experience was with TFS 2008) when things went wonky and that usually fixed the issue.