# When saving file that is monitored by TFS getting error: Cannot be saved because write-protected

Tags: visual-studio

When I open the visual studio (2010 - professional), i am getting the following error:
"The associated source control plug in is not installed or could not be initialized vs 2010"
I tried all the recommended solutions here: [[TFS Error: "Source Control - Unable to Access Database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081405/tfs-error-source-control-unable-to-access-database][1]) But nothing worked.
Is it possible that i have some problem with my VS? Maybe i am missing a Service Pack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the following are installed on your computer:

1. Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1
2. Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server Compatibility GDR https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082
3. Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (KB2736182) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34677

I was missing (2) and (3), after their installation I didn't get the error "The associated source control plug in is not installed or could not be initialized vs 2010" anymore upon opening the visual studio, and was able to save the modified files as usual.

Tip: check the solution on another machine.
If it opens without any errors then the solution above probably will work for you.