# Is this warning about from VSS?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I'm trying to remove the vestiges of Visual SourceSafe (VSS) from an old code base I have on my PC. (The back-end server where the VSS database was kept is long since gone.) I had thought all I had to do was delete all of the files with extensions of .scc and .vssscc. Then I tried to create a local Git repo where the Visual Studio project was in. I tried opening the project with Visual Studio 2019, but got this error:

[image]

Is this error/warning that VS is informing me of from some other old file associated with VSS that I failed to remove? I certainly don't have a plug-in in VS 2019 for VSS, so that would make some sense. I'm just trying to make sense of this warning and what I'm supposed to do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [git-tfs/git-tfs issue 109](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/109)

> Visual Studio uses the unfortunate practice of storing TFS binding information in solution and project files.
>
> When I pull those files into Git, VS warns me that "The associated source control plug-in is not installed or could not be initialized. Common causes for this error include server unavailability and/or incorrect workspace mappings."
>
> I can then choose to "Temporarily work uncontrolled" or "Permanently remove source control bindings".

Try and [import from source control your repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5265283/6309), assuming *all* VSCode project/solution files are deleted first.